# How to feed my own data and evaluate at TF text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained and tested my own data as given instruction at `How to build a simple text classifier with TF-Hub` the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/text_classification_with_tf_hub). Everything is fine and works well. Now I want to predict other data without labeled and want to see the predicted result. But I could not find the proper way at the codes below. I need to get predicted results for `remain` data below.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from absl import logging
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir)
file_name="traindata.txt"

train_df = {}
test_df = {}
remain = {}

with open (file_name, 'r', encoding="utf8") as l:
  lines = l.readlines()

with open ('remain.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8" ) as l:
    remain_data = l.readlines()

remain["html"] = [i.lower() for i in remain_data]


train_df["html"] = [i.lower() for i in lines[:1100]]
test_df["html"] = [i.lower() for i in lines[1100:]]

with open ('trainlabel.txt', 'r') as l:
  labels =  l.readlines()
  labels = [int(i) for i in labels]
  train_df["polarity"] = labels[:1100]
  test_df["polarity"] = labels[1100:]


train_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(train_df)
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_df)
remain_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(remain)

# Reduce logging output.
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)


# Training input on the whole training set with no limit on training epochs.
train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(train_df, train_df["polarity"], num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

# Prediction on the whole training set.
predict_train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(train_df, train_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)

# Prediction on the test set.
predict_test_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(test_df, test_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)

# Prediction on the remain  set.
predict_remain_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(test_df, test_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)

embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key="html",
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/random-nnlm-en-dim128/1")

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[64, 32],
    feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
    n_classes=2,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.003))

# Training for 5,000 steps means 640,000 training examples with the default
# batch size. This is roughly equivalent to 25 epochs since the training dataset
# contains 25,000 examples.
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=5000)

train_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_train_input_fn)
test_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)


print("Training set accuracy: {accuracy}".format(**train_eval_result))  ## Ressult %99,
print("Test set accuracy: {accuracy}".format(**test_eval_result))       ## Result ~ %79,
```

I am newby and thanks for help in advace.

Answer (score 0):

For this first you need to change

```
# Prediction on the remain  set.
predict_remain_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(test_df, test_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)
```

to

```
# Prediction on the remain  set.
predict_remain_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(remain_df, remain_df["polarity"], shuffle=False)
```

and then to predict result

```
remain_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_remain_input_fn)
print("Remain set accuracy: {accuracy}".format(**remain_eval_result))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @khimraj-suthar, But  there is no key of `polarity` at `remain` dict